# invoke system calls from multiple processes

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I have implemented a new system call in Linux:

```
void do_test(unsigned char *input, unsigned char *output){
    unsigned char *pt;     
    // do something complex with pt; 
}
```

The `do_test` system call are invoked by many processes running in Linux.

Should I be worried about multiple processes having race conditions for the shared variable `*pt` (i.e. it is in inconsistent state)? Or is this the case that each process will have its own version of the kernel code, so that `*pt` used in process A is not the same as one in process B?

If there's race condition, how should I lock it?

Comment: modify the code to pass a pointer to the function.  as it is, the *pt is not being set to anything.  suggest: void do_test( unsigned char *pt) {... }

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the new system call for?

Comment: i edited the question to show that the system call combines the user supplied input with some internal kernel state. For example, it signs the user input with its private key.

Comment: What does `pt` point to?

Comment: "for the shared variable" - I don't see any shared variables. I see a local variable.

Comment: Implementing a new system call is usually a mistake. It's almost always more appropriate to implement new functionality in terms of existing calls on new objects (e.g, open/read/write on a new device or `/proc` object).

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned char *pt;` is a local variable, it's not shared since each process has it's own stack for syscalls. They share the same code, but it runs on a different stack.

So no, if you stick to local variables, you don't need any locks and you don't risk any data race.